# How can i make 1 Column with multiple rows including a Div?

Tags: html, sharepoint, html-table

I have 6 buttons in a single column, 2 of the buttons are Divs so they can have a drop down pop out.  I also have 2 headers but i don't have them labeled as headers cuz they are just section titles.

```html
<div style="float:left;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top"></td>
      <td width="50"></td>
      <td valign="top">
        <h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: large; color: black; font-weight: bold; background-color: gold; width: 215px; border-radius: 5px; margin: 8px 5px 5px 5px;">POLICIES & INSTRUCTIONS</h1>
        <a class="ui small reverse button" id="uibutton" href="link" style="width:170px; margin:18px 5px 5px 5px;" target '+_blank">link 1</a></br>
          <a class="ui small reverse button" id="uibutton" href="link" style="width:170px; margin:18px 5px 5px 5px;" target'+_blank ">link 2</a></br>
          <div class="dropdown ">
               <button class="ui small reverse button " style="width:215px;margin:5px; " type="button " onclick="console.log( 'fix'); ">Diagrams</button>
               <div class="dropdown-content ">
                    <a href="Link " target="_blank ">title 1</a>
                    <a href="Link " target="_blank ">title 2</a>
                    <a href="Link " target="_blank ">title 3</a>
               </div>
          </div>
          <h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: large; color: black; font-weight: bold; background-color: gold; width: 215px; border-radius: 5px; margin: 8px 5px 5px 5px; ">EXTERNAL LINKS</h1>
          <div class="dropdown ">
               <button class="ui small reverse button " style="width:215px;margin:5px; " type="button " onclick="console.log( 'fix'); ">Help</button>
               <div class="dropdown-content ">
                    <a href="Link " target="_blank ">title 1</a>
                    <a href="Link " target="_blank ">title 2</a>
                    <a href="Link " target="_blank ">title 3</a>
               </div>
          </div>
          <a class="ui small reverse button " id="uibutton " href="link " style="width:170px; margin:18px 5px 5px 5px; " target'+_blank">link 3</a>
        </br>
        <a class="ui small reverse button" id="uibutton" href="link" style="width:170px; margin:18px 5px 5px 5px;" target '+_blank">link 4</a></br>
          </td>
     </tr></table>
</div>
```

When i put this in everything follows 1 column except the last 2 a classes, they go off on their own column.  I read in previous psts about Div inside tables needing their own  but that did not fix anything it just made it worse, showed everything out in 3 different columns.

Comment: HTML error : `target'+_blank"`

Comment: Note that the `valign` attribute has been obsolete for 20 years or more.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to create a layout with buttons and dropdowns using HTML and CSS, but you're encountering issues with the alignment of the elements. To help you address the problem, I'll provide you with a cleaner and more structured version of your code that should help you achieve your desired layout. In this version, I'll use flexbox for better alignment control and separate the styles from the HTML for clarity:

```css
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .section-title {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: large;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: gold;
    width: 215px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 8px 5px;
  }

  .button-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 5px;
  }

  .ui.button {
    width: 170px;
    margin: 18px 5px;
  }

  .dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="section-title">POLICIES & INSTRUCTIONS</h1>
  <div class="button-container">
    <a class="ui small reverse button" href="link" target="_blank">link 1</a>
    <a class="ui small reverse button" href="link" target="_blank">link 2</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="ui small reverse button" onclick="console.log('fix');">Diagrams</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="Link" target="_blank">title 1</a>
        <a href="Link" target="_blank">title 2</a>
        <a href="Link" target="_blank">title 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h1 class="section-title">EXTERNAL LINKS</h1>
  <div class="button-container">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="ui small reverse button" onclick="console.log('fix');">Help</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="Link" target="_blank">title 1</a>
        <a href="Link" target="_blank">title 2</a>
        <a href="Link" target="_blank">title 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="ui small reverse button" href="link" target="_blank">link 3</a>
    <a class="ui small reverse button" href="link" target="_blank">link 4</a>
  </div>
</div>
```